# Invoking HTPS WebService from java

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, wsdl

I am trying to access a web service which has SSL enabled from stand alone java program . I was able to generate client from WSDL however when i am trying to invoke web service i get SSL handshake issue . Below is java code

```
TestWebService sh = (TestWebService) shs.getTestWebServiceExportTestWebServiceHttpPort();
                     BindingProvider port = (BindingProvider)sh;

               port.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.
                          ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, args[0]);
               System.out.println( ((BindingProvider)sh).toString() );
```

The url that is lets say https://service.test.com/sca/TestWebService?wsdl

Below is the error message

Failed to access the WSDL at:

```
https://service.testwebservice.com/TestWebServiceExport?wsdl. It failed with: 
       Got com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
       java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Corp Production Root CA V1, O=Cord Inc. is not trusted; internal cause is: 
       java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error while opening stream from https://service.testwebservice.com/TestWebServiceExport?wsdl.
```

I have installed the ceritificate in IE browser from website but still no luck .

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track by installing the cert into IE browser - that would allow IE to access the web service without error. However, as your client is Java (and not IE), you need to install the cert into Java.

The Java command for doing this is as follows:

```
$JAVAHOME/bin/keytool -import -alias service.test.com -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file ~/certfile.pem
```

Note: this will install the cert into the default keystore for that Java install.  This will affect all Java processes using that JVM. The default password for the keystore is 'changeit'

Comment: Thanks , this solution works however i have to  add "java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=mykeystore ... MyClientClass"   java VM parameter is there any way we can avoid this i have seen programs which dont use this.

Comment: The cacerts file is the default trust store for the VM - provided you've added the cert to the correct cacerts file you shouldn't have to specify a trustStore manually as a VM parameter.  If you are having to specify the file, it's possible you may have added the cert to the cacerts for, say, a different java install